# How do I stop databound child form from changing its current item when it's parent form changes its current item?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, bindingsource

I've got a DataSet that contains a table of "Clients" and a table of "Bookings".  There is a DataRelation set up between the two, "ClientsBookings".

I've bound the Clients table to a DataGridView in the parent form.  When a row is double clicked, a new child form is opened for the selected client which displays the clients details and it's associated bookings.

At the moment, each new form seems to be bound to the current item in the parent form.  So when the row in parent table changes, so does the current item in every opened child form.  I thought that creating a new BindingSource in the child form and setting it's position would make its current item independent of the parent form's binding source (It didn't work).

Currently, I've chained two BindingSources together in the child form using the "ClientsBookings" relation.  This ensures only bookings related to the current client are displayed in the child form.  If I instead pass in a DataRow or something similar, I can't figure out how to get this same effect.

Anyways, here is the code so far:

**Parent form:**

```
public partial class ClientsSearchForm : Form
{
    BindingSource bsClients = new BindingSource();

    private void ClientsSearchForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet clientsDataSet = GetDataSet();
        bsClients.DataSource = myDataSet;
        bsClients.DataMember = "Clients";
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bsClients;

        this.dataGridView1.CellDoubleClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick);
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        ClientForm form = new ClientForm(bsClients);
        form.Show();
    }

}
```

**Child form:**

```
public partial class ClientForm : Form
{
private BindingSource bsClients = new BindingSource();
private BindingSource bsBookings = new BindingSource();

public ClientForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public ClientForm(BindingSource bsClients)
{
    private BindingSource bsClients = new BindingSource();
    private BindingSource bsBookings = new BindingSource();

    public ClientForm(BindingSource bs)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // set up client binding source
        // Note: intent is to have this form associated with only one client
        // and not change when the selection on the search forlm changes.
        this.bsClients.DataSource = bs.DataSource;
        this.bsClients.DataMember = bs.DataMember;
        this.bsClients.Position = bs.Position;

        // set up bookings binding source
        this.bsBookings.DataSource = this.bsClients;
        this.bsBookings.DataMember = "ClientsBookings";

        // set up control bindings
        textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsClients, "Given Name");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bsBookings;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, I think I found the solution.  Pass DataRowView to constructor of the child form, then set it to a BindingSource: "this.bsClients.DataSource = this.dataRow;".  This is then chained to the bookings binding source in the same way as I did before.

Comment: Is this the correct way to do it?